# Where I made mistake(s) as the integrating of $~\int_{}^{}\frac{1}{\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}\,dx~$?

Tags: integration

$$L:=\int_{}^{}\frac{1}{\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}\,dx\tag{1}$$

$$=\int_{}^{}\sin^{-2}\left(x\right)\,dx\tag{2}$$

$$=\frac{\sin\left(x\right)^{-1}}{\left(-1\right)\left(\cos^{}\left(x\right)\right)}+\text{const}\tag{3}$$

I did the following to gain eqn3

1. Incremented the index by 1, of the integrand$~\sin^{-2}\left(x\right)~$
2. The incremented index value$~\left(-1\right)~$was appended to the denominator.
3. Appended the$~\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sin^{}\left(x\right)\right)=\cos^{}\left(x\right)~$to the denominator.

$$L=-\frac{1}{\sin^{}\left(x\right)\cos^{}\left(x\right)}+\text{const}~~\leftarrow~~\text{Wrong answer.}\tag{4}$$

The correct integration equation is$~L=-\cot\left(x\right)+\text{const}~$

Where I made mistake(s)?

Comment: Step 3 is incorrect. It means that you can replace $\cos x\,dx$ with $d(\sin x)$, but only BEFORE integration. Correct use would be, for example,
$$
\int\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x}\,dx=\int(\sin x)^{-2}\,d(\sin x)=-\frac1{\sin x}+C.
$$ You may be confused by the fact that when there is a *constant* multiplier (instead of $\cos x$ like here), you can bring that outside of the integral.

Comment: To say @JyrkiLahtonen's comment a different way: substitution shows that an indefinite integral of $f'(g(x))g'(x)$ is $f(g(x))$. It does not imply that an indefinite integral of $f'(g(x))$ is $\frac{f(g(x))}{g'(x)}$. And indeed randomly chosen functions will verify that this last statement is false. (Remember, you can always take the derivatives of the alleged antiderivatives you find to check whether they are correct!)

Comment: Step 2: $\sin^{-1}x\ne\left(\sin x\right)^{-1}$

Comment: @Vega do you mean to say correct use of brackets?

Comment: @Vega I know it , arcsin .

Comment: @UnexpectedConfusion Yes, even though he has not used it in that sense, it is still a good practice to use brackets properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{(\sin x)^2}dx &=\int\frac{(\sin x)^2+(\cos x)^2}{(\sin x)^2}dx \\
&=\int dx + \int (\sin x)^{-2}(\cos x)^2 dx\\
&=x + \int \cos x (\sin x)^{-2} d(\sin x)\\
&=x+\int \cos x d(-\sin x)^{-1})
\end{align}

Integration by parts gives

$=x-(\cos x)(\sin x)^{-1}+\int (\sin x)^{-1}d\cos x$
$=x-ctg x-\int \frac{\sin x}{\sin x}dx=-ctg x$

Comment: The "(" is needed to be appended I think at 4th row.

Comment: Yes it must be $d((\sin x)^{-1})$.